# Salesforce Lightning, unable to pass parameter from JS Helper to APEX Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to call an Apex Controller method from JS Helper of the Lightning component. But when I try to pass a parameter of the type of a custom object the apex method is not getting invoked.

I don't understand what is causing this error, no error is shown on Debug Log. There are no namespaces used in the org.

Kindly help me out.

I have shared the code fragment.

**Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="MSIApplicationFormLightningController">

  <aura:attribute name="application" type="Applications__c" />

  <div aura:id="page-content" class="toggle">

      <ui:inputText value="{!v.application.Major__c}"
                    class="slds-input question-input" 
                    required="true" />      

       <div class="button-grid">
           <ui:button class="custom-button" label="SAVE DRAFT" press="{!c.saveApplicationAsDraft}"/>
       </div>

  </div>

</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller**

```
({       
    saveApplicationAsDraft: function(component, event, helper){

            helper.saveApplication(component, event);

    }

})
```

**JS Helper**

```
({
    saveApplication: function(component, event){  

        var action = component.get("c.saveMSIApplication");


        action.setParams({ "application" : component.get("v.application")});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){          

            console.log(response.getState());

            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));

            if(component.isValid() && response.getState() == "SUCCESS"){

                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            }

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
})
```

**APEX Controller**

```
public without sharing class MSIApplicationFormLightningController {

  @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveMSIApplication(Applications__c application){

      String appId = 'test';


      return appId; 
    }

}//End of class
```

**Console log**:

```
 "ERROR" for response.getState() 
 "null" for response.getReturnValue()
```

Comment: Try logging `response.getError()` and see what it tells you

Comment: How are you supplying `application` to your component? It's not set on `init` nor is a `default` value declared.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everybody, after specifying the default attribute value the Apex Controller method got invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always declare a default value for your attribute so that it is not undefined

```
<aura:attribute name="application" type="Applications__c"  default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Applications__c',
                      'Major__c':''
 }">
</aura:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, after specifying the default attribute value the Apex Controller method got invoked.